# sql - how to make this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql

I spent few days trying to figure it out already, but with no luck!

I have tables as so:

```
user:
id, name

event:
id
userId
startAt
endAt
```

How to write a query that will get all users that:

- don't have events assigned
- or have events that do have start and end (are completed)
- and don't have events that don't have endAt
- This could be described as available users.

Here is my (unsuccessful) attempt:

```
SELECT *
FROM user
LEFT JOIN event ON user.id = event.userId
WHERE
 startAt IS NOT NULL AND endAt IS NOT NULL
OR  event.userId IS NULL
```

Here is sql fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa55cd

The above query should return 3 users. User with id 1 should be skipped, as they . have event with no end date.

Comment: Your query works. The problem is the test data in your fiddle. It contains two rows for the event table for `userId =1`. Your query is properly excluding the event for `userId` 1 where `endAt` is NULL.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `NOT EXISTS` in a correlated subquery to find "available" users:

```
SELECT *
FROM user u
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM `event` e
    WHERE e.userId=u.id
      AND e.startAt IS NOT NULL
      AND e.endAt IS NULL
)
```

[Demo.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa55cd/7)

```
id  Name
--  -------
2   Michael
3   Jenny
4   June
```

Comment: Great solution,i had exactly the same problem

Answer (score 1):

Use a subquery to eliminate users which have events without `endAt`

```
SELECT *
FROM user
LEFT JOIN event ON user.id = event.userId
WHERE user.id NOT IN (
    SELECT userId
    FROM event
    WHERE endAt IS NULL)
```

[SqlFiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/aa55cd/21)